# Query Image File of a Different Size

Tags: images

I know that when you upload an image to the Wordpress media library, it automatically creates some duplicates of that image in different sizes. I'd like to know how I can return those differently sized image files.

The solution I'm currently using is this:

```
<?php
$image = get_field('image');
$imageurl = $image ['url'];
?>

<img src="<?php echo str_replace(".jpg","-800x500.jpg",$imageurl); ?>">
```

This is fine, but I'm looking for a function native to wordpress that would do this. Like querying an array of these differently sized files of the same image.

Note that wp_get_attachment_image_src and functions like it are not what I'm looking for. Even though you can set a size to be returned, it doesn't change the file in question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what data is in your `get_field('image')` but it sounds like you want all the metadata associated with an image. To do that just pass the `$id` to [`wp_get_attachment_metadata()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_metadata).

The result would be:

```
Array
   (
       [width] => 2400
       [height] => 1559
       [file] => 2011/12/press_image.jpg
       [sizes] => Array
           (
               [thumbnail] => Array
                   (
                       [file] => press_image-150x150.jpg
                       [width] => 150
                       [height] => 150
                       [mime-type] => image/jpeg
                   )
               [medium] => Array
                   (
                       [file] => press_image-4-300x194.jpg
                       [width] => 300
                       [height] => 194
                       [mime-type] => image/jpeg
                   )
               [large] => Array
                   (
                       [file] => press_image-1024x665.jpg
                       [width] => 1024
                       [height] => 665
                       [mime-type] => image/jpeg
                   )
               [post-thumbnail] => Array
                   (
                       [file] => press_image-624x405.jpg
                       [width] => 624
                       [height] => 405
                       [mime-type] => image/jpeg
                   )
           )
       [image_meta] => Array
           (
               [aperture] => 5
               [credit] => 
               [camera] => Canon EOS-1Ds Mark III
               [caption] => 
               [created_timestamp] => 1323190643
               [copyright] => 
               [focal_length] => 35
               [iso] => 800
               [shutter_speed] => 0.016666666666667
               [title] => 
           )
   )
```

Comment: great! thank you. this is exactly what I'm looking for.